# Agrupar contenido por día y mes

Tags: tsql, transact-sql

Estoy intentando agrupar y contar registros de cada día, pero no me sale como debería salirme.

La estructura de la tabla es muy simple:

```
 ____________________________
| Id  |   Dato   | fechaHora |
|_____|__________|___________|
| AI  | Varchar  | DateTime  |
|_____|__________|___________|
```

Y esta es la consulta que estoy intentando

```
SELECT CONVERT(DateTime,GETDATE(),101) as 'Dia', COUNT(*) as 'cantidad'
  FROM table
  Group by DAY([fechaHora]), MONTH([fechaHora])
  //Grup by [fechaHora]
  //Group by Convert(DateTime,GETDATE(),101), COUNT(*) as 'cantidad'
```

Creo que estoy rizando el rizo y debe de haber alguna forma más sencilla para poder agrupar, si no me equivoco y a pelo en SQL sería algo como.

```
SELECT TO_Date(fechaHora,'dd-mm'), count(*)
FROM Table
Group by TO_DATE(fechahora,'dd-mm').
```

El problema es que en vez de agruparme por mes y día me agrupa todo por días, entonces tengo 31 días  en total en vez de tener 31 días por mes.

La idea es que el resultado quede como:

```
 ___________________________
| Dia  |  Mes  |  Cantidad  |
|______|_______|____________|
| 30   |  03   |    54      |
|______|_______|____________|
| 01   |  04   |    124     |
|______|_______|____________|
| 02   |  04   |    42      |
|______|_______|____________|
```

Comment: Hola podrias poner un ejemplo de como quisieras el resultado? Te importa la hora de la fecha o solo el dia como "2019-07-24" y cuantos hubieron de ese dia?

Comment: @EdgarVazquez con retraso pero ya lo he actualizado, disculpa.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que te estás complicando. Esto debiera ser lo que buscas:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, fechaHora, 111) AS 'Fecha',
       COUNT(*)                         AS 'Cantidad'
       FROM table
       GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR, fechaHora, 111)
```

Esto agrupa por día (año - mes - día) y cuenta las filas.

Answer (score 0):

Hola podrias intentar algo como esto
El codigo que uso al principio solo es para simular insert en mi tabla

```
--Declaramos una variable tipo tabla para simular la tabla
DECLARE @TableDemo TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Dato VARCHAR(50),
FechaHora DATETIME
)

--Hacemos un CTE que obtenga numeros solo para concatenar a la columna Dato
;WITH L0 AS (SELECT C FROM(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1)D(C)),
      L1 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L0 CROSS JOIN L0 B),
      L2 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L1 CROSS JOIN L1 B),
      L3 AS (SELECT 1 C FROM L2 CROSS JOIN L2 B),
      L4 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) AS Num FROM L3),
      SelectFirst50 AS (    
--Hacemos un top 60 para traernos solo 60 registros     Usamos el dateadd para agregar dias a la fecha actual
SELECT TOP 60 'Dato'+CAST(Num AS varchar(50)) AS Dato,DATEADD(DAY,Num,GETDATE()) AS FechaHora
FROM l4),
SelectFinal AS (
--Hacemos lo mismo que lo anterior pero ahora usando otro nombre de dato pero los mismos dias para tener dos registros por una fecha
SELECT TOP 60 'Dato1.1'+CAST(Num AS varchar(50)) AS Dato,DATEADD(DAY,Num,GETDATE()) AS FechaHora  
FROM l4
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM SelectFirst50)
--INSERTAMOS LOS REGISTROS
INSERT INTO @TableDemo
SELECT * FROM SelectFinal

--Select DATENAME lo puedes omitir yo lo tengo solo para ver el mes
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,FechaHora) AS Mes,
--Obtenemos el dia
CAST(FechaHora AS date) as 'Dia', 
--Obtenemos cuantos por dia
COUNT(*) as 'cantidad'
FROM @TableDemo 
--Agrupamos por dia y mes
Group by DAY([fechaHora]), MONTH([fechaHora]),CAST(FechaHora AS date),DATENAME(MONTH,FechaHora)
ORDER BY MONTH([fechaHora]) ASC
```

Saludos cualquier duda aquí andamos.